# how to pass a large list of ids to the where clause in sqlite3 batch mode?

Tags: sqlite

I have a large list of ids I want to use for a query in sqlite3. I can loop one by one in the shell, perl or R, or do clever hacking with xargs or ',' concatenating in order to query by batches in order to be more efficient but I was wondering if there is a way of loading directly the file in a temp table or do a 'where  in ([read file]). Which is the standard way of dealing with this common situation?

Comment: You mean `sqlite3`, the command-line shell, right?

Comment: yes, but not the interactive mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean sqlite3 the command-line shell, right?

Yes, that one has an option to load file, in something-separated format, in a (temporary) table.

```
create temporary table ids (id integer primary key);
.import ids.txt ids
```

Where `ids.txt` would have each id on separate line. If you wanted to import multiple columns, you'd have to set separator using the `.separator` command beforehand, but for only one column it shouldn't matter.

Note that `integer primary key` is faster than any other column type because it aliases row id and sqlite stores tables in b-trees indexed by rowid. So use it if you can.

Answer (score 0):

I came with a large one line solution: create a string of comma separated and quoted elements, and pipe to xargs. xargs will put as many of them as they are allowed in the comand line and repeat the command as many times as necessary.

If I have a tab separated file with my elements in the second column:

```
perl -lane ' push @x,$F[2]; END{ print join(", ",map{q{\"}.$_.q{\"}}@x)}' file.txt |\
xargs -t -I{}  sqlite3 -separator $'\t' -header database.db \
 'select *  from xtable where mycolumn in ('{}') and myothercolumn="foo" order by bar"
```